# ValueError when converting String to datetime in Python

Tags: python

I have a Dataframe `df` and I am trying to find the difference, in months, between `df['maturity_dt']` and todays date and use the code below to do this, but I get the error `ValueError: time data '2015-12-31 00:00:00.0' does not match format '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'`. I guess I don't know how to refer to the last `0` in `00:00:00.0`

```
def months_to_maturity_func(d1, d2):
    return abs((d2 - d1).months)

todays_date = datetime.date.today()

for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
    row['months_to_maturity'] = months_to_maturity_func(todays_date, datetime.datetime.strptime(row['maturity_dt'], '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Thank You

Comment: Use `%f` for micro-secondes.

Comment: And also replace the `%b` with `%m`. The following works for me: `datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-12-31 00:00:00.0', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong format , try using - `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` .

`%b` is for three letter month abbreviations like - `Jan` , `Feb` , etc.

And use `%f` at the end for microseconds.